# How to prevent implicit caching in Spring Boot 1.5.1 Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to understand why, after creating a new entity and persisting it whilst the application is running, when retrieving a list of these entities, the new entity should be retrieved from the database, but isn't?

For example:

I created a new entity (from the UI) and persisted it successfully like so:

```
@Repository
public class BaseDAOHibernate {

    Session session;

    public BaseDAOHibernate() {

        session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public void save(Object object) {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(object);
        tx.commit();
    }
...
```

I verified that the entity is persisted in the database.

Next, when I refresh the UI which lists these entities (for which I added a new one to the database) the new entity is not included and was not retrieved from the following:

```
@Repository
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class PasswordDAOHibernate extends BaseDAOHibernate implements PasswordDAO {

    @Override
    public Collection<Password> getPasswords() {

        Query query = session.createQuery("select ...");
        return query.list();
    }
```

Here is the interface:

```
public interface PasswordDAO {

    Password getPassword(Integer id);

    Collection<Password> getPasswords();

    Collection<Password> getPasswords(PasswordSearchParameters params);

    Collection<PasswordType> getPasswordTypes();
}
...
```

Which is called from a controller:

```
@Controller
public class PasswordsController extends BaseControllerHelper {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordDAOHibernate passwordDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/passwords.htm")
    public void passwords(Map model,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        Collection<Password> passwords = passwordDAO.getPasswords();
        model.put("passwords", passwords);
    }
```

Here is the configuration currently setup:
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://host:3306/server</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.User"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.Role"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.Property"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.Menu"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.Password"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.crm.entity.PasswordType"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtils.java

```
@Component
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

When I restart the server application the new entity displays in the list.

Is there some kind of implicit caching going on that I need to clear? Note, I have not implemented any explicit caching at this stage.

Comment: Huh? There's no way you need to manually manage sessions and transactions if you're using spring-data, you just need to extend JPARepository and use `@Transactional` annotation on the service methods

Comment: Hibernate itself should be managed by Spring based on properties from `application.properties` where you set up your data source

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Should I need to implement JPARepository in Spring Boot

Comment: @DarshanMehta Adding `@Transactional` to `PasswordDAOHibernate` class and `BaseDAOHibernate` class did not work.

Comment: @crm look at [this example code](https://github.com/balintbabics/SpringBoot-with-MySQL-Books/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties)

Comment: You dao is flawed, very flawed... Never open a single session and reuse. Always get the current session in dao methods.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your dao, which is flawed in a very dangerous way. A `Session` isn't thread safe and shouldn't be shared. It should be opened for each action (or at least the current session should be used).

### Plain Hibernate Solution

You DAO should look something like this.

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected BaseDAOHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void save(Object object) {
    getCurrentSession().save(object);
}
```

Now you specific dao should reuse the `getSession` method.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PasswordDAOHibernate extends BaseDao implements PasswordDao {

@Autowired
public PasswordDAOHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public Collection<Password> getPasswords() {
    return getSession.query("select ...", Password.class).list();
}
```

When doing so you probably will run into issues with an error stating that *no session can be found due to no transaction* (or something along those lines).

To fix this use Spring Boot (and some manual configuration).

First move the `hibernate.connection` properties to your `application.properties` and remove them from `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/server
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password
```

Now Spring will create a `Datasource` for you. Next remove your `HibernateUtils` and configure the `SessionFactory` using Springs `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return factory;
}
```

You will also need the appropriate transaction manager

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
}
```

Now due to everything being setup in Spring, the injection of the `SessionFactory` and the `@Transactional` you will get a managed `Session` which will be properly opened and closed for you.

### Controller Fix

Your controller is also flawed as you should be injecting a `PasswordDao` and not the concrete type (which would now fail due the the creation of a proxy for the transactions).

```
@Controller
public class PasswordsController extends BaseControllerHelper {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordDAO passwordDAO;
```

### JPA Solution

However while all of this will probably work I would strongly suggest to use JPA and the `EntityManager` instead of the `Session` and `SessionFactory` approach.

To do so remove the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and the `HibernateTransactionManager` and add the remaining properties of the `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the `application.properties`.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Next to the `spring.datasource` properties that is all you need and you can delete the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Now instead of using the `SessionFactory` use the `EntityManager` in your dao.

```
public abstract class BaseDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void save(Object o) {
        em.persist(o);
    }
}
```

And your specific dao.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public PasswordJpaDao extends BaseDao implements PasswordDao {

@Override
public Collection<Password> getPasswords() {
    return em.createQuery("select ...", Password.class).getResultList();
}
```

### Spring Data JPA Solution

When using JPA you could even drop your generic dao approach and implementations and use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) instead. Your whole `PasswordDao` would then look like

```
public interface PasswordDao extends JpaRepository<Password, Long> {}
```

All the crud functionality (`findAll`, `findOne`, `save` etc.) is available out-of-the-box. Creating queries is pretty easy and saves you from writing the boilerplate code.

Comment: Why do you suggest using the JPA solution over plain Hibernate?

Comment: Because it is easier to setup and use with Spring Boot it works out-of-the-box. Next to that most tutorials nowadays are based on JPA and not plain Hibernate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Cacheable(false)` on your entity

or disable the shared cache altogether for all your entities by adding this to your `persistence.xml`

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

For Hibernate you can also use

```
session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
```

see [this link](http://www.developer.com/java/using-second-level-caching-in-a-jpa-application.html) for more information about the different cache levels in JPA

Comment: it's standard behavior to use the second level cache unless you disable it

Comment: I tried adding `@Cacheable(false)` to the entity and added `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);` to the dao call. Neither worked. The new entity is not retrieved when the page is refreshed.

Comment: can you try using `session.createSQLQuery` to make sure that a native query does retrieve from database?

Comment: Query is working at application start. Problem occurs when persisting a new entity during application run and some cache not being updated/refreshed/evicted...